# how to make incremental backup in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I'm trying to make incremental backup but its occur syntax error, plz guide someone

```
 mysqlbackup --incremental-with-redo-log-only \--incremental-base=dir:/home/admin/Desktop/shellscript \--incremental-backup-dir=/home/admin/Desktop/shellscript/incrementalbackup \backup;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$ mysqlbackup --incremental-with-redo-log-only \--incremental-base=dir:/home/adm' at line 1